# Will a string of 5W globe bulbs in patio survive the rain?

Tags: lighting, waterproof

I have a string of 5W globe bulbs (G12) in patio. The bulbs are facing upwards. A few questions

What will happen if:

1. If I turn them on after it has rained and things are wet
2. I turn them on during rains
3. I turn them on when everything is dry. - I've already tried this and some of the bulbs glow, while others are burnt out. A few of them have their top exploded.

Followup: Is it possible to use globe string lights in wet weather at all?

Comment: Check if it is rated for outdoor use or not.

Comment: On construction sites I have seen them inside weathertight housings before (strung from outdoor cord), or under a roof at restaurants in third world countries where they are not so worried about electrical codes. But not bare bulbs exposed directly to rain. I suspect it is not workable.

Comment: Having the bulbs upwards is asking for trouble - rain water will run around the bulbs and into the socket.  If you have the bulbs downward, you wmay have a chance of it working, if the sockets are water resistant in that position.

Comment: Not to mention the thermal shock from water falling directly onto the bulb glass is also what is probably responsible for them exploding.

Answer (score 1):

Look for an IP rating when you buy your next set of lights. IP44 or higher should meet your needs for outdoor rain protection.

More details about IP ratings here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code

Comment: Will do. Would these ratings be printed on the wire string? These were already in the house and I don't have the box.

Comment: Given the problems you describe they definitely weren't IP44 rated. It's not likely to be labelled on the wire but it would be on the box for a new set